# How to suppress repetitions of specific first chance exceptions from 3d-party component if I have NOT access to its source code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, filter, tracelistener, first-chance-exception

My program in C# 4.0 is using 3d-party library through which launches a process of for continuously getting the flux of data through DDE from external source on the internet.

After launching the process it is getting in Visual Studio 2010 Output window the endless repetitions with a frequency of few dozens per second of just 2 lines:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in 3dPartyLibIUse.DLL  
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Is there any way to **filter out** these repetitions (after initial output of these two lines) or these specific exceptions but not first chance exceptions at large if I do not have access to source code of 3d-party dll?

**Update:**
The main problem is that I do not have access to source code of that used 3d-party library, it is obfuscated and meddling with it by its License immediately invalidates all the rights of its usage.

But I still essentially need the exception, warnings and errors output from it which is cluttered by thousands of omnipresent repetitions of just 2 exceptions

Comment: did you already try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.filter.aspx